# Why does DBCC TRACEON (1204, 1222) not work?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, trace-flags

I have executed DBCC TRACEON (1204, 1222) on several servers.

Some of them simply do not turn the trace flags on. The command brings the same expected informational message for each but some simply do not react.

DBCC TRACESTATUS(1204, 1222) delivers  0, 0, 0 in this case for both flags.

Why do they ignore it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running just `DBCC TRACEON (1204, 1222)` is per session level.

You should run `DBCC TRACEON (1204, -1)` globally.

See [BOL- DBCC TRACEON](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187329.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more details.

Comment: Yes, Sir, this seems to be my mistake here. However I still wonder why it did not even display on session level that it has been turned on...

Comment: @Magier maybe there is some issue here. There was another similar Q on StackOverflow recently http://stackoverflow.com/q/38836287/73226